# xsd-makepkg package is not loading correctly through go get command

Tags: go

```
$ go get -u github.com/metaleap/go-xsd/xsd-makepkg 

/home/mypc/go/src/github.com/metaleap/go-util/fs/watcher-default.go:32:22: undefined: fsnotify.FileEvent
/home/mypc/go/src/github.com/metaleap/go-util/fs/watcher-default.go:64:35: undefined: fsnotify.FileEvent
/home/mypc/go/src/github.com/metaleap/go-util/fs/watcher-default.go:72:44: undefined: fsnotify.FileEvent
/home/mypc/go/src/github.com/metaleap/go-util/fs/watcher-default.go:79:18: me.Event undefined (type *Watcher has no field or method Event)
/home/mypc/go/src/github.com/metaleap/go-util/fs/watcher-default.go:83:21: cannot assign type func(<T>) to onEvt (type func(<T>)) in range
/home/mypc/go/src/github.com/metaleap/go-util/fs/watcher-default.go:97:18: me.Error undefined (type *Watcher has no field or method Error)
/home/mypc/go/src/github.com/metaleap/go-util/fs/watcher-default.go:119:15: me.Watch undefined (type *Watcher has no field or method Watch)
```

Answer (score 0):

github.com/metaleap/go-xsd is ["stale since 2013"](https://github.com/metaleap/go-xsd) so its not too suprising it no longer works. If you check github you will see the comment "MAINTAINED FOR YEARS NOW: try the forks if running into issues. [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/12g6sl/is_there_a_tool_that_generates_go_source_code_for/)"

In this case the reason for the error you are getting is that `github.com/metaleap/go-xsd/xsd-makepkg` uses `https://github.com/metaleap/go-util`. `go-util` imports  `github.com/go-forks/fsnotify` and, on line 32 in [watcher-default.go](https://github.com/metaleap/go-util/blob/master/fs/watcher-default.go#L32), attempts to use `OnEvent []func(evt *fsnotify.FileEvent)`. Unfortunately in the time since `go-util` was released the `fsnotify` package has been updated and no longer has `FileEvent` (removed some time around 2014).

I would suggest finding an alternative package. If you really want to use this one you could retrieve an early (pre 1.0) version of `fsnotify` (but I would not advise it as there have probably been a lot of fixes since then).

Note: More modern packages using go modules should not suffer from this issue (because dependencies can be locked to a specific version).

Comment: Also see https://github.com/metaleap/go-xsd/issues/37